# 'str' object does not support item assignment in Python, Web-scraping

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping

I'm trying to restructure already existing/working code of mine.
Changes are made inside the second for loop.
Why do I get the error when changing my code from this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

games_played = []
stats_for_games = []
for game_id in range(2017020001, 2017020010, 1):
    url = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/{}/boxscore'.format(game_id)
    r_2017 = requests.get(url)
    game_data_2017 = r_2017.json()

    for homeaway in ['home','away']:

        game_dict_2017 = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('teamStats').get('teamSkaterStats')
        game_dict_2017['team'] = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')
        game_dict_2017['homeaway'] = homeaway
        game_dict_2017['game_id'] = game_id
        games_played.append(game_dict_2017)

print(games_played)
```

To this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import requests
import json
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

games_played = []
stats_for_games = []
    for game_id in range(2017020001, 2017020010, 1):
    url = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/{}/boxscore'.format(game_id)
    r_2017 = requests.get(url)
    game_data_2017 = r_2017.json()

    for homeaway in ['home','away']:

        game_dict_2017 = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')
        game_dict_2017['homeaway'] = homeaway
        game_dict_2017['game_id'] = game_id
        games_played.append(game_dict_2017)

print(games_played)
```

When running it, the error TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

shows up on

```
 game_dict_2017['homeaway'] = homeaway
```

Sample of JSON-data

```
{
copyright: "NHL and the NHL Shield are registered trademarks of the 
National Hockey League. NHL and NHL team marks are the property of the 
NHL and its teams. © NHL 2019. All Rights Reserved.",
teams: {
     away: {
         team: { 
                id: 9,
                name: "Ottawa Senators",
                link: "/api/v1/teams/9"
 },
teamStats: {
    teamSkaterStats: {
                   goals: 0,
                   pim: 0,
                   shots: 0,

 }
 }
```

Comment: `game_dict_2017 = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')` in this linw you are taking a value of the dictionary and trying to take another value and another, etc.

Unless you have nested dictionary of dictionaries, it will not work out.

Comment: The JSON-data is nested dictionaries, thats why I'm using that method. Worked previously

Comment: Can you add a sample of the data that you are trying to work with? I consider that you just by mistake overwrite `game_dict_2017` to a string in `game_dict_2017 = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')` and later try to work with `game_data_2017` as it was before assignment.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly do you want to restructure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally understood what is the problem.

The previous code was:

```
# In this line you created a dictionary
game_dict_2017 = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('teamStats').get('teamSkaterStats')

# Here, since you have dictionary you rewrote values or created new one
game_dict_2017['team'] = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')
game_dict_2017['homeaway'] = homeaway
game_dict_2017['game_id'] = game_id
games_played.append(game_dict_2017)
```

Current code is:

```
# Here you are getting a string
# You previous code was 
# game_dict_2017['team'] = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')
game_dict_2017 = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')

# Here you are trying to work with a string as with dictionary
game_dict_2017['homeaway'] = homeaway
game_dict_2017['game_id'] = game_id
games_played.append(game_dict_2017)
```

In order to fix this issue and assuming that you don't need `game_dict_2017 = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('teamStats').get('teamSkaterStats')` line anymore code will look like:

```
game_dict_2017 = dict()
game_dict_2017['team'] = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')
game_dict_2017['homeaway'] = homeaway
game_dict_2017['game_id'] = game_id
```

You also can do it this way:

```
game_dict_2017 = {
    'team': game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name'),
    'homeaway': homeaway,
    'game_id': game_id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    game_dict_2017 = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')
```

This line returns a string, i.e 'Winnipeg Jets'.
A quick fix would be to initialize game_dict_2017 first and then set a dict key as the team name.

**Example:**

```
    game_dict_2017 = dict()
    game_dict_2017['teamname'] = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')
    game_dict_2017['homeaway'] = homeaway
    game_dict_2017['game_id'] = 2017020001
    games_played.append(game_dict_2017)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    game_dict_2017 = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')
    game_dict_2017['homeaway'] = homeaway
    game_dict_2017['game_id'] = game_id
```

This is the issue.

You define `game_dict_2017`, I suppose it's a string. And then try to use it as dictionary, I suppose you messed `game_dict_2017` and `game_data_2017`.